# (Done) Request to reopen question about expensive applicant hosting

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[What point does company's generosity during the interview process have?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122314/what-point-does-companys-generosity-during-the-interview-process-have)

There are solid and widely used business reasons this may happen, not just opinion. It's also useful knowledge to have. I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reopened successfully, thanks everyone who voted.